# Flask Documentation for @app.route('/upload/<filename>')

Tags: json, python-3.x, file-upload, flask, interactive

Is there anywhere in the Flask documentation 1.0, 0.12.x or older documentation that actually explains how to implement correctly flask uploads. I've been coding for 30 years now and I can not get my head round any of the flask documentation. And I mean any of it other than the hello world example. Every example contains info like, "and one more thing you will need". This means that the documentation/code is not complete. Its bitty at best.

In particular, there is no clear explanation of:

```
@app.route('/upload/<filename>')
```

What is filename? is it a variable? is it a placeholder? is it something that the return variable assigns? what is the function of the <> signs? What is the way to preserve a global view of 10-20 variables other than using JSON? None of this is clear and yet is fundamental to building any non-trivial website.

When generating a sample flask/html based websites I cannot find code to:

1. upload a file and forward the filename into another template from a starting template.
2. shows the complete set of working code and code structure.

Some upload_file() functions (flask documentation) are showing the rendered pages whilst others (user websites/stack overflow) are returning an address of a file. I've managed to render a page without returning the filename so I've no clue why people are writing /upload in addition to upload_file.

A few stackoverflow examples show two functions that are both called upload_file() one that posts and one that is supposed to display an image. This throws an error in flask 0.12.4 (under Debian Stretch).

I guess somebody has documentation on how to generate a website with "Step 1, step 2, step 3, final" type setup where each page is rendered by flask. Currently, I can't find anything like this.

Am I the only one at a loss? I can see that if you are expert in this, you can then write HTML/Python Interactive websites without any PhP which is very appealing for me, since I'm already expert in Python.

```
SUB_FOLDER = 'tables/uploads'
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/var/www/html/{}'.format(SUB_FOLDER)
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png',
                          'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])


@app.route('/runtable', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def first_table():
    if request.method != 'POST':
        my_table = [{"text": "line one", "code": 0},
                    {"text": "line two", "code": 1}]
        return render_template('step1.html',
                               my_table=my_table)


@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = request.files['file']
        filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                                secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(filename)
        fullFileName = os.path.join('http://localhost/',
                                    SUB_FOLDER,
                                    secure_filename(f.filename))
        jsonItem = [{"text": "Sample table header", "code": 0},
                    {"text": "second line of text", "code": 2}]
        return render_template('step2.html',
                               my_table=jsonItem,
                               filename=fullFileName)
    pass
```

Comment: What an amazing piece of documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#file-uploads  NOT! I especially love the ... So self-explanatory.

Comment: `<>` is a [Rule Format](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/routing/#rule-format)

Comment: @RajaSimon Okay this is useful... I think. But what is it, is it a variable, a declaration of some sort, a placeholder for something? I still don't get it. Maybe, I'm stupid. I've used restful stuff lots of times before but I don't get this.

Comment: @RajaSimon If i write a post upload_file method that renders a page how does filename get stored and used in the other functions. The examples are half complete and its hard to tell what is being used in the templates and what is used in the flask functions. This is probably the main source of my confusion. I've implemented all the examples and none of them work. I built my own by messing around with a combination of many pieces of documentation and still don't know quite how it works.

Comment: I'm not recommanding this method but have you tried copy paste those examples blindly and try it works. After that remove some code and run the server. And figure out why it's not working. Good luck.